# How to detect IIS vs. self-hosted OWIN process

Tags: asp.net, compression, owin, dnx

I am building a new OSS project that is both relevant to IIS and OWIN-based (new .NET Core/DNX) projects.

For backwards-compatible functionality, I need to call WMI scripts to check if a given Windows feature - dynamic content compression for IIS - is installed.
In a self-hosted environment, however, this is irrelevant as middleware can compress content on-the-fly.

How do I tell the difference between a self-hosted OWIN project and an IIS-hosted one with C# code?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: No, sadly, I forked the IIS-hosted parts into a separate library instead.